# If $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^p$ and $g_n \rightarrow g$ in $L^q$, where $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$, show that $f_n g_n \rightarrow fg$ in $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I know that this will have something to do with Holder's inequality but I am at a loss as to how the $L^p$ and $L^q$ convergence in $f$ and $g$ dictate the convergence in $L^1$. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/251817/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: 
$$f_n g_n - fg = (f_n-f)g_n + (g_n-g)f$$
Second hint:
$$\int |f_n g_n - fg| \le \int |f_n - f| |g_n| + \int |g_n - g| |f|$$

Comment: I've tried using this convention of adding zero. But doesn't that only tell you about pointwise convergence everywhere and not use the Lp convergence?

Comment: @user211071: See second hint.

Comment: SO I can use Holder's inequality on both parts of the sum on the right?

Comment: @user211071: Yes, exactly!

Comment: Great. Thanks Nate!